# How do I remove decimals from Pandas to_dict() output

Tags: python, pandas

The gist of this post is that I have "23" in my original data, and I want "23" in my resulting dict (not "23.0").  Here's how I've tried to handle it with Pandas.

My Excel worksheet has a coded Region column:

```
23
11
27
(blank)
25
```

Initially, I created a dataframe and Pandas set the dtype of Region to `float64*`

```
import pandas as pd
filepath = 'data_file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheetname=0, header=0)
df
```

---

```
23.0
11.0
27.0
NaN
25.0
```

Pandas will convert the dtype to `object` if I use `fillna()` to replace NaN's with blanks which seems to eliminate the decimals.

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df
```

---

```
23
11
27
(blank)
25
```

Except I still get decimals when I convert the dataframe to a dict:

```
data = df.to_dict('records')
data
```

---

```
[{'region': 23.0,},
 {'region': 27.0,},
 {'region': 11.0,},
 {'region': '',},
 {'region': 25.0,}]
```

Is there a way I can create the dict without the decimal places? By the way, I'm writing a generic utility, so I won't always know the column names and/or value types, which means I'm looking for a generic solution (vs. explicitly handling Region).

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: that's because you are converting column Region to float64: try int instead. This is the command to do that . `pd.to_numeric(series_obj, errors='coerce')`

Comment: @VikashSingh If the column has `NaN` then it will be coerced to float anyway.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah just tried it not working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom function, takes care of integers and keeps strings as strings:

```
import pprint

def func(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

df = pd.DataFrame({'region': [1, 2, 3, float('nan')],
                   'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', float('nan')]})
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
pprint.pprint(df.applymap(func).to_dict('records'))
```

Output:

```
[{'col2': 'a', 'region': 1},
 {'col2': 'b', 'region': 2},
 {'col2': 'c', 'region': 3},
 {'col2': '', 'region': ''}]
```

A variation that also keeps floats as floats:

```
import pprint

def func(x):
    try:
        if int(x) == x:
            return int(x)
        else:
            return x
    except ValueError:
        return x

df = pd.DataFrame({'region1': [1, 2, 3, float('nan')],
                   'region2': [1.5, 2.7, 3, float('nan')],
                   'region3': ['a', 'b', 'c', float('nan')]})
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
pprint.pprint(df.applymap(func).to_dict('records'))
```

Output:

```
[{'region1': 1, 'region2': 1.5, 'region3': 'a'},
 {'region1': 2, 'region2': 2.7, 'region3': 'b'},
 {'region1': 3, 'region2': 3, 'region3': 'c'},
 {'region1': '', 'region2': '', 'region3': ''}]
```

Comment: This is part of the question `By the way, I'm writing a generic utility, so I won't always know the column names and/or value types, which means I'm looking for a generic solution (vs. explicitly handling Region).`

Comment: Please formulate your question accordingly. My answer solves the problem you describe in your question.

Comment: Agreed But you also didn't read the whole question. + The question is not mine. So Don't know how to pitch it here.

Comment: My answer does not assume any special column names or number of columns.

Comment: Please read the question properly. User does not want -9999. Ze want's the original Value *exact* value to be specific. Also not all columns will be int convertible. Some columns in the Excel sheet could be String. Could be Float. You will loose info in such cases.

Comment: @VikashSingh Thanks for your persistence. Added a improved solution.

Comment: This looks much better @Mike. Thanks :)

Comment: Works great!  Thanks Vikash for your persistence.  Thanks @Mike for putting together a total solution!  Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that after `fillna('')` your underlying values are still `float` despite the column being of type `object`

```
s = pd.Series([23., 11., 27., np.nan, 25.])

s.fillna('').iloc[0]

23.0
```

Instead, `apply` a formatter, then replace

```
s.apply('{:0.0f}'.format).replace('nan', '').to_dict()

{0: '23', 1: '11', 2: '27', 3: '', 4: '25'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add: `dtype=str`

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = 'data_file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheetname=0, header=0, dtype=str)
```

Comment: Hello Ludwig, your answer gives a solution to the question. To make your answer even better, you could try to explain why your solution works.